# Consolidate columns with null values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reporting the rows which are having null values of source and target like below

```
df_out[df_out.isnull().any(1)]
```

[image]

but to get the output in efficient and readable way, is there any way i can get consolidating all columns which are having null like below?

[image]

for reference i am giving my entire code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_source= pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df_target= pd.read_csv('target.csv')
df_all = pd.concat([df_source.set_index('id'), df_target.set_index('id')], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['Source', 'Target'])
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_source.columns[1:]]
df_out = df_final.style.set_table_styles([caption_styles,select_styles,table_styles, tbody_styles,td_styles, th_styles]).set_caption("Test Case 1").apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
df_out=df_out.data
df_out[df_out.isnull().any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native pandas way to do this, but you could just iterate over all the rows and columns in a nested list comprehension, adding the column name to a list for each row if the respective value is null:

```py
df_null = df_out.isnull()

df_out['Columns_with_null'] = [[col for col in df_null.columns
                                    if df_null[col][i]] 
                               for i in df_null.index]
```

Comment: Thanks. But my dataset is huge and using loop will take huge time right?

Comment: The time will increase linearly with the number of rows (barring memory issues), so you could try it on a subset of rows and extrapolate how long it would take for the entire dataset.